# XMLUnit 2.0 - Unable to avoid order comparison with custom Element selector

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit-2

first of all thank you for this wonderful library, it's really great.

I'm having a problem comparing elements in different order within my xml document. I've developed a custom ElementSelector to use with the NodeMatcher (later the code) but still it seems to check based on element order more than element content.
Let me write an example

Control

```
<Parent>
<Person>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<LastName>Doe</LastName>
<Email>johndoe@email.com</Email>
</Person>
<Person>
<FirstName>Mickey</FirstName>
<LastName>Mouse</LastName>
<Email>mm@email.com</Email>
</Person>
<Person>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<LastName>Doe</LastName>
<Email />
</Person>
</Parent>
```

Test

```
<Parent>
<Person>
<FirstName>Mickey</FirstName>
<LastName>Mouse</LastName>
<Email>mm@email.com</Email>
</Person>
<Person>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<LastName>Doe</LastName>
<Email>johndoe@email.com</Email>
</Person>
<Person>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<LastName>Doe</LastName>
<Email />
</Person>
</Parent>
```

How I made the Diff

```
Diff diff = DiffBuilder.compare(refSource)
                        .withTest(testSource)
                        .checkForSimilar()
                        .ignoreWhitespace()
                        .normalizeWhitespace()
                        .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(selector))
                        .build();
```

How I created the ElementSelector selector

```
ElementSelector selector = ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
                        .whenElementIsNamed("Person").thenUse(new PersonNodeMatcher())
                        .defaultTo(ElementSelectors.byNameAndText).build();
```

How is actually implemented the PersonNodeMatcher

```
public class PersonNodeMatcher extends BaseElementSelector {

@Override
protected boolean canBeCompared(Element control, Element test) {

    String controlFirstName = control.getElementsByTagName("FirstName").item(0).getTextContent();
    String controlLastName  = control.getElementsByTagName("LastName").item(0).getTextContent();

    Node controlEmailNode = control.getElementsByTagName("Email").item(0);
    String controlEmail = null;
    if ( controlEmailNode != null) {
        controlEmail = controlEmailNode.getTextContent();
    }


    String testFirstName = test.getElementsByTagName("FirstName").item(0).getTextContent();
    String testLastName  = test.getElementsByTagName("LastName").item(0).getTextContent();


    Node testEmailNode = test.getElementsByTagName("Email").item(0);
    String testEmail = null;
    if (testEmailNode != null) {
        testEmail = testEmailNode.getTextContent();
    }

    return bothNullOrEqual(controlFirstName,testFirstName) &&
              bothNullOrEqual(controlLastName,testLastName) &&
              bothNullOrEqual(controlEmail,testEmail);

}
```

The routine is still checking the nodes in order, so they will never match.
I thought that providing a node custom node matcher I would be able to check all the Element with the tagName provided.

Am I doing something wrong or simply is not possible?

[UPDATE]
Using the alpha3 I had to do some modification to the code, specifically:

```
ElementSelector selector = ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
                        .whenElementIsNamed("Person").thenUse(new PersonNodeMatcher()).build();


    Diff diff = DiffBuilder.compare(refSource)
                        .withTest(testSource)
                        .checkForSimilar()
                        .ignoreWhitespace()
                        .normalizeWhitespace()
                        .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.or(selector,ElementSelectors.Default)))
                        .build();
```

Comment: which alpha of XMLUnit 2 are you using? It may be the implementation of conditionalBuilder prior to alpha3 - https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit/issues/40

Comment: I was using alpha2, I'm now trying with alpha3

Comment: [Update] Same problem with the alpha3, seems not able to pick the correct "control" element.

Comment: ah, overlooked your definition of `DefaultNodeMatcher`. Please use the varargs constructor rather than `or` - i.e.  `new DefaultNodeMatcher(selector, ElementSelectors.Default)`.

Comment: I used the varargs constructor and I was able to pair correctly the nodes, still I get this error that I don't understand (the xpath is not important): Expected child nodelist sequence '8' but was '12' - comparing <Person...> at /BioSampleGroup[1]/Person[1] to <Person...> at /BioSampleGroup[1]/Person[5]...what does this mean?

Comment: By default elements that are in different order result in a "SIMILAR" comparison outcome. Your elements *are* in a different order and XMLUnit tells you so. If you don't care you can either be content with testing for "similar" or add a `DifferenceEvaluator` that downgrades this specific difference to "EQUAL".

Comment: So something like this should be fine or there's a better way of write it?    //other code .withDifferenceEvaluator(((comparison, outcome) -> { if (outcome == ComparisonResult.DIFFERENT && comparison.getType() == ComparisonType.CHILD_NODELIST_SEQUENCE) { return ComparisonResult.EQUAL; } return outcome; })) 
//other code

Comment: you should probably `chain` your implementation with `DifferenceListeners.Default` and drop the check of outcome. If this works for you, we should turn this into an answer, StackOverflow doesn't like long discussions in comments ;-)

Comment: Yep, we can do that. Thanks :-)

Comment: I suggest you write the answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I moved to the most recent alpha, the alpha-03. There was an issue with the alpha-02;
2. Instead of using the `ElementSelectors.or` inside of the `DefaultNodeMatcher`, I used the `varargs` constructor

   ```
   Diff diff = DiffBuilder.compare(refSource)
                          .withTest(testSource)
                          .checkForSimilar()
                          .ignoreWhitespace()
                          .normalizeWhitespace()
                          .withNodeMatcher(
                                new DefaultNodeMatcher(
                                       selector,ElementSelectors.Default)
                          )
                          .build();
   ```

   The difference between the two approaches is explained [here](https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/SelectingNodes#elementselectorsnot-and-or-and-xor).
3. This solved my primary issue, still there was a problem since the `DifferenceEvaluator` was outputting that document were different, due to [this](https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/SelectingNodes#defaultnodematcher-elementselector-and-nodetypematcher) (look at the end of paragraph). Indeed, the document are `SIMILAR` and not `IDENTICAL`, since the order of the inner elements is not equal. In order to prevent such an output from the `DifferenceEvaluator`, at the moment I've updated the `DiffBuilder` with a specific `DifferenceEvaluator`

   ```
   .withDifferenceEvaluator(((comparison, outcome) -> {
       if (outcome == ComparisonResult.DIFFERENT && 
           comparison.getType() == ComparisonType.CHILD_NODELIST_SEQUENCE) {
              return ComparisonResult.EQUAL;
       }

       return outcome;
   }))
   ```

   even if probably the best solution, as suggested by [Stefan Bodewig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4524982/stefan-bodewig), would be to `chain` my implementation with `DifferenceListeners.Default` and drop the check of outcome.